# origin of a linked server

Tags: sql-server, database

I used [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451566/view-linked-server-dependencies-sql-server-2008) to determine what databases are using the 5 linked servers on a SQL server.

However, the results don't make sense to me. It is telling me that a server "DOMAIN" is being used by many databases for views, but when I look at the design of the view, I do not see [DOMAIN] in the SQL statement. 
Example:
 
The query result shows me that the database [StrongMailTracking] depends on the linked servers [DOMAIN] and [SDMASQLSRV05.WISPUBS.UCG.COM] for the view [vw_SCP]. 
When I look at the design of [vw_SCP] I see:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ucontactid, vemail, vfirstname, vlastname, domain, vcompanymapped, vcompanyname
FROM            SDMASQLSRV05.WISPUBS.UCG.COM.MarketingPromotions.dbo.selected_contacts_prelim AS a
```

When I go Linked Servers and expand DOMAIN, there aren't any tables or views. When I try to expand the System tables and views, I get an error:

> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server...
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

Any thoughts on what's going on here?

Comment: Do you use the same credentials for that View accessing the Linked server and your SSMS?

Comment: @SlavaMurygin different credentials. However the server has been there for a long time. As you can see, the View does not reference the DOMAIN server

Comment: Then check if your account, which you use in SSMS has proper rights on the linked server.